# Настройка Webpack для использования import/require ES6

Tags: javascript, webpack

Используя **Webpack**, как можно настроить loader, что бы получать файл через импорт используя путь

```
import User from 'elements/user';
```

сама структура проекта имеет такой вид

```
elements/user/user.js
```

**user.js** нужно брать автоматически исходя из аналогичного название папки (аналог работы файла по умолчанию **index.js**) То есть папка и файл должны быть одинаковы.
Если у кого-то есть хорошее решение помогите плиз.

Answer (score 6):

Есть специальный плагин [component-directory-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/sebastiandeutsch/component-directory-webpack-plugin), настраивается следующим образом:

**Установка:**

`npm i component-directory-webpack-plugin -S`

**Настройка:**

```
// webpack.config.js
var ComponentDirectoryPlugin = require('component-directory-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  resolve: {
    plugins: [new ComponentDirectoryPlugin()]
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

в доках вебпака нашла другой плагин
https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolveplugins

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]